# Cannot see Youtube Content ID API to enable

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I got error while trying to update Youtube Video asset

**Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/contentOwners?fetchMine=true: (403) Access Not Configured. The API (Youtube Content ID API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.**

But I cannot find the Youtube Content ID API in my dev console. I'm using a Youtube Account with a channel that is Youtube Partner. What's wrong with that? :(

Answer (score 2):

> You don't see it in the list auf available APIs, unless your account
>   is connected to a CMS and some time has past... It takes 7-14 days
>   unless the Content ID API is available for your account. This is a
>   information i got from the support, but they told me, that it is an
>   automated step. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28148304/327301)

Too bad the official documentation does not mention that your account needs to be connected with a CMS account... For whatever reason.

Note that a CMS account and a partner account are not the same things.