# Getting access to YouTube Content ID API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My original purpose is to get all of the channels that a user manages. I found a code snippet that does exactly that: https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/code_samples/python#retrieve_a_content_owner_s_managed_channels

However, it seems to rely on the YouTube Content ID API, when I run it I get the following error:

```
YouTube Content ID API has not been used in project ... before or it is disabled.
```

However, the YouTube Content ID API doesn't show in the projects console. I manage several YouTube channels, and one of them is part of the YouTube Partner Program. So, my question is, how do I get access to the YouTube Content ID API?

I've been reading about this for several hours and found several conflicting statements.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner), saying:

> As a YouTube partner, you can use the API...

[Here](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/86713102/how-to-get-access-to-youtube-content-id-api?hl=en), saying:

> in order to be able to access the ContentID API, you have to be part of
> the ContentID Partner Program, not the YouTube Partner Program.
> However, you're not likely going to have ContentID access if you don't have major copyright management control issues

Which is weird, since the data I need has nothing to do which copyrights at all, so why would I need an API that relates to that to get it?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111212/how-do-i-get-revenue-reports-from-a-youtube-cms-account-using-an-api-for-an-mcn/28148304#28148304), saying:

> You don't see it in the list auf available APIs, unless your account
> is connected to a CMS and some time has past... It takes 7-14 days
> unless the Content ID API is available for your account. This is a
> information i got from the support, but they told me, that it is an
> automated step.

So, which one is it? If I'm only part of the YouTube Partner Program, should I just wait for 2 weeks until the API shows up in my console?
Or does it actually require to be in the ContentID Partner Program (which is not the case here)?